# Запеченный свет проходит сквозь стены

Tags: c#, unity3d

Запекаю свет в закрытом помещении, но он проходит сквозь стены. Через режим отображения посмотрел разрешение лайтмапы и вижу, что у стен разрешение нормальное, а у пола, потолка и т.д. растянутое. Понятно то, что разрешение растягивается на всю поверхность, потому что закрытое поле у меня довольно большое. Как поделить объект так, чтобы на каждый его кусок было не растянутое разрешение. (слишком много слова "растягивание")[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Под стенами на полу надо сделать рёбра. На этих рёбрах сделать разрыв UV. Иначе билинейная фильтрация гигантских пикселей лайтмэпа будет "протаскивать" свет под стенами. Ещё одна вещь на туже тему: когда UV раскладки лайтмэпов пакуются в одну текстуру (атлас), между соседними отобржениями кусков UV должны быть промежутки в два пиксела минимум. Иначе свет соседнего куска UV будет виден в данном куске UV как баг (билинейная фильтрация). Добро пожаловать в мир процедурных текстур!

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Мысль понял, но у меня карта сделана через ProBuilder, а стены стоят как отдельные объекты. Можно ли как-то через ProBuilder это провернуть?

Comment: Разделите пол на прямоугольники. Не соединяйте их по рёбрам. Просто набор прямоугольников, которые не имеют общих рёбер. Тогда любому роботу придётся уважать ваше решение. Когда наберётесь опыта, будет знать где резать действительно надо, а где нет.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Пару раз прочитал и что-то начал понимать. Попробую так сделать позже, при результате отпишу.

Comment: Ещё один подход - оказаться от отдельного пола. Сшейте пол со стенами (стены должны иметь толщину). Пола в простенках быть не должно. У этого решения есть то преимущество, что свет на стене и на полу рядом будет более плавно меняться.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy Хм, это тоже попробую, спасибо.

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy вы уже написали на небольшой ответ. Предлагаю оформить, бесполезным не будет.

Comment: Это только предположения. Если вы их подтвердите, с вас и ответ с картинками.